# after installing node, node is not detected when first open terminal

Tags: node.js

[image]

- i install node in zsh terminal.. node sucessfully installed
- but to use it  i have to switch in bash terminal then switch again to zsh terminal
- i dont know why this happen.

beside solution can you tell me whats happening in background

i expect to use node without switch between bash first and switch again to zsh

Comment: How did you install node?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should better use code snippet instead of an image for a better searchability

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned how you installed `node` and what all steps you've tried, my hunch is that the config isn't loaded in your `zsh` session.

Could you try to reload your `zsh` config?

Try this command in `zsh` terminal:

```
exec $SHELL -l
```

Judging by what you mentioned, it looks like `node` is installed in your system and is in the path as well, but the terminal config isn't loaded.

If this command doesn't solve the issue, I'd suggest:

- Quit all the instances of the terminal and then open a fresh terminal
  and try.
- Try to reboot your system (if you haven't already) and try once.

P.S: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "i install node in zsh terminal". How did you set it up so that it only works in `zsh` and not the `bash` one?

Comment: i install node when terminal sann@sann is in blue color( so i think thas is in zsh)

Comment: Umm, the color of the Terminal won't indicate the shell type. Did you try any of the things I mentioned?